# Javascript table is not rendering using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, scrollable-table

I created a table using JavaScript, but it doesn't render using my css. so how can I make it work? actually i need more help, my idea is to create a screen that has one button and once you click on it a menu which is a table of one column starting at the top of the screen and end at the end of the screen should be showing. the table would be scrollable and each row has text (url text) with no url line under the text, so when you click on it the page open in all of the screen behind the table and the button. the button should be always showing (but it disappears when i click on it).
the main.js file is

```
     function makeTableHTML() {
    var x = document.createElement("TABLE");
    x.setAttribute("id", "myTable");

    var myArray = [ [ "Name, http://www.google.com" ],
            [ "Name, http://www.google.com" ] ];
    var result = '<table width = "300">';
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        result += "<tr><td>";
        if (i < 10) {
            result += "0" + i + "  ";
        } else {
            result += i + "  ";
        }

        result += '<a href="' + myArray[i][0] + '">';

        result += myArray[i][1] + "</a>";

        result += "<td></tr>";

    }
    result += "</table>";
    document.write(result);
    document.getElementById("channelsmenu").classList.toggle(result);
}

function hideTableHTML() {
    var x = document.getElementById('channelsmenu');
    x.style.display = 'none';
}
```

and my html is

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>5Star-IPTV</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="channelsmenu" class="dropdown-content"></div>

                </td>
                <td class="buttons-col"><input type="image"
                    src="channels-menu.png" class="buttons" alt="channels menue"
                    onMouseOver="this.src='channels-menu-1.png'"
                    onMouseOut="this.src='channels-menu.png'" onclick="makeTableHTML()" /></td>
                <td class="buttons-col"><input type="image"
                    src="return-button.png" alt="return button" class="buttons"
                    onMouseOver="this.src='return-button-1.png'"
                    onMouseOut="this.src='return-button.png'" onclick="hideTableHTML()" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the css

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #808080;
}

tr {
    width: 100%;
    align: right;
}

th, td {
    text-align: right;
}       background-color: #808080;
}

.buttons-col {
    text-align: center;
    width: 90px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: So, where is your CSS?

Comment: sorry i forgot about it as I have many classes in the css file. you can check it now. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

in  HTML you open "th" and close it as "tr". Secondly, please learn to write/format your code properly - it'll be easier to read your code and to help you.

Besides, use the < script > tag at the end of the HTML or run your JS in the function on event DOMContentLoaded

Comment: This is not suitable as an answer. It should be a comment.

Comment: sorry it was already over 10:30 or 11 pm when wrote this question but i couldn't post it just today. yep it is tr but i kept changing and changing so mistakenly posted th instead tr. the script is in main.js file not in the html that is why i an not using <script>.

Comment: It's not too late. Just copy the text and post it as a comment. Then delete the answer.

Comment: sorry. I'm new here and didn't know how it works.
I'm trying to do what u suggested, but there is an info 'you must have 50 reputation to comment' so I cannot ;/

Comment: Thanks for tour respond, I already updated my question to have the latest codes I have